# How To Change Only The Title Background Color Of A Div Tag In Jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui-dialog, title

I have a div tag in my modal dialog built using JQuery like this: div id="dialogxxxx" title="xxxxx" . I want to just change the font and background color of the title alone, i.e. only the place where the title is displayed. Right now it has a default color and font. I want to change it to a specific color, but do not want to change the background color and font of the entire div, just the place where the title is displayed. Is there a way to do this? I tried adding style tag to the div, but that changes the background color of the entire div, not the title alone. I also tried doing div#title, that didnt help either.

Any pointer/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Asha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick-n-dirty way, you can simply override the `.ui-widget-header` css rule, e.g.

```
.ui-widget-header {
  background: red;
}
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/NgVAu/.

If you want a more maintainable approach, you should use the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), configuring the "Header/Toolbar" section. If you open up your css file, you can find a URL to the ThemeRoller with the theme it's using. It is located in the second lot of comment, after "To view and modify this theme", e.g.

```
/*
 * jQuery UI CSS Framework @VERSION
 *
 * ...
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API
 *
 * To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?...
 */
```

Comment: Thanks William, I tried the quick-and-dirty approach. Its works. I will try out the other approach as well. Thanks again